# serve a 404 when a locale file is missing in express

Tags: node.js, express, yeoman-generator-angular, i18next

I'm using DaftMonk's [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/775), which has been great, except for one small problem I'm having...

I'm using i18next to handle localization, and the way the library works is it attempts to load a locale file from your specified path for the user's given localization setting, ie: `/locales/en-US/app.json` -- if that doesn't exist, it tries `/locales/en/app.json` (and in my case finds the file here).

The problem is the way the generator works is it has a route catchall which redirects all 404s to the `index.html` (the entry point for an angular app). This allows dynamic routing for the single page app.

When this happens, `i18next` chokes because it was expecting either a `404` or a json locale file, but instead got the `index.html` page.

I need a way to exclude the `/locales` path from being handled by this wildcard catch all and serve a `404` rather then the `index.html` page if a file is missing.

Here is what the express wildcard does:

```
//is there anyway to write an exclusion to this `/*` wildcard?
app.route('/*')
    .get(middleware.setUserCookie, index.index);

/**
 * Send our single page app
 */
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        name: pkg.name,
        version: pkg.version,
        env: config.env
    });
};

//in dev mode
app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'app')));

//in production mode
app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));
```

How can I write a rule that will redirect `/locales/*` to serve a 404 if the file isn't found, rather than redirect to `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (/\/locales\//.test(req.originalUrl) {
    send404function()
}
```

Maybe it's not `app.use()`, but hopefully you wouldn't have to do this too much.